# Cassandra CLUSTERING ORDER BY not doing what I'd expect

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I'm pretty new to Cassandra, I have created a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notifications (
  id uuid,
  raised timeuuid,
  recorded timeuuid,
  customer varchar,
  region varchar,
  location varchar,
  operator varchar,
  till varchar,
  receipt_id varchar,
  value decimal,
  details text,
  is_refund boolean,
  has_promos boolean,
  utc_offset int,
  frame_count int,
  expecting_video boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, raised)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (raised desc);
```

And then inserted 1,000 rows from the DataStax .NET Cassandra adapter like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
                    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    var now = DateTime.Now;

                    var insertNotif = session.Prepare(@"
                    INSERT INTO notifications 
                    (id,customer,region,location,operator,till,receipt_id,value,details,is_refund,has_promos,raised,recorded,utc_offset,frame_count,expecting_video)
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,now(),now(),?,?,?)");
                    var insertNotifStatement = insertNotif.Bind(id, "cust1", "reg1", "loc1", "tomm", "london", i.ToString(), i % 10.99D, "DATA_HERE", false, true, (int)TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(now).TotalMinutes, 0, false);

                    session.Execute(insertNotifStatement);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

What I'd expect to happen is that all the records will be stored in time descending order based on the `raised` column. When I use CQLSH to inspect the data, it appears to be in a random order:

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> select dateOf(raised) from notifications limit 5;

 dateOf(raised)
--------------------------------------
 2014-06-03 11:12:45GMT Daylight Time
 2014-06-03 11:12:48GMT Daylight Time
 2014-06-03 11:12:56GMT Daylight Time
 2014-06-03 11:12:32GMT Daylight Time
 2014-06-03 11:12:34GMT Daylight Time

(5 rows)
```

Have I done something wrong?
BTW, I have also tried to set `raised` to a timestamp column and expected the same behaviour (but I passed in DateTimes from .NET instead of now()), but it behaves in the exact same way.

How can I get my records **store and retrieved** in time descending order?

Comment: order by is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an eq or an in..

Comment: I'm not using ORDER BY, I was expecting the records to be stored in date descending order because of the clustering order defined in the schema. By querying the data, I am expecting the data to be returned in the order defined by Clustering Order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clustering order refers to the ordering within the partition i.e. for the same ID. So if you inserted multiple rows with different `raised` values and queried, you would see them returned in descending order.

The order you are seeing is the order of IDs. As you observed, these are essentially random. This order is the partitioner order i.e. ordered by the hash of the ID.

You can't change this order, so you can't read all your partitions back in time order. You can only order within each partition.

Comment: Good info thanks, so how do I go about retrieving all notifications in date desc order?

Comment: You can't unless you put them all in the same partition. But then you don't get any scalability. If you need to read in all your data, you could use Hadoop or Shark.